# SSH : "Connection reset" for one of my LXC's

Tags: bash, ssh, lxc

I've been stuck for a while about my ssh connection to one of my LXC's.
Indeed, when I connect in ssh to my other LXC, everything works.
However, one does not want to connect and displays this error:

```
ssh root@mysite.lxc
```

> Connection reset by 10.0.3.12 port 22

I do not want to use the following command ...

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

... because my SSH connection works well for my other sites.
Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the LXC container on a Proxmox host, you can try to enter the container through the host with 'pct enter ' instead of using a separate SSH connection.